select part of png image jetpack compose
im creating a map that shows avalable seats of a place . user have to choose the reagion of the map for ezample red one and afther that click on seat that wants to reserve
i have  problem with noticing which part of he map did user clicked

what do you think i should do . i have svg file too . is there any way use svg file to seperate elements ?
using offset and useing canvas are useful but when screen size changes its very hard to handle
